# Castle Windsor - not sting default constructor parameter

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have the class implementing the interface

```
public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
public class MyComponent : IMyComponent
{
    public MyComponent(Address address)
    {
        this.Value = address;
    }

    public Address Value { get; private set; }
}

public interface IMyComponent
{
    Address Value { get; }
}
```

And I want to be able to bind it to interface using CastleWindsor like this

```
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

                    container.Register(
                        Component.For<IMyComponent>()
                        .ImplementedBy<MyComponent>()
                        .Parameters(Parameter.ForKey("address")
                            .Eq(new Address {City = "New York", Street = "street"})));
    var component = container.Resolve<IMyComponent>();
```

The problem is I can't pass `Address` to Eq function. Is there a way to pass not-string parameter to constructor using CastleWindsor?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DependsOn` method to pass the value.

Comment: @Krzysztof..   it didn't worked in mine program .. it gives compilation error 
"cannot convert from 'windsorPoly.Square' to 'string'"